# how to test google places apis in localhost and getting the client id

Tags: google-maps

I want to use the places api for getting the places names within a circle in localhost. Does anyone know how to get the client id for localhost?

Comment: Did you generate an API key for localhost http://groups.drupal.org/node/769?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I am looking at doing a similar thing.

Comment: @moontear, there is no support for localhost for Places api, you have to get a client id through adsense

Answer (score 4):

I'm using Visual Studio and when I debug locally the URL is:

```
http://localhost:2386/index.html
```

To connect to Google API I set the following two properties of the Client Id in the API Access tab of the Google API console:

```
Redirect URIs:          http://localhost:2386/oauth2callback

JavaScript origins:     http://localhost:2386
```

I'm using the Analytics API but hopefully this will help in your case as well.

Comment: 2386 is the port assigned by Visual Studio.  It will most likely be different for your project.  You can find it be running your web application and looking at the URL.  It will be http://localhost:XXX where XXX is your port number.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for but a possible workaround could be:

1. Get to know the IP of your computer (e.g.: http://whatismyipaddress.com/)
2. Add your IP in this Format (http://xx.xx.xxx.xx/) to the Google Console (https://developers.google.com/console/)
3. Use the API-Key for testing.

Be sure that your IP doesn't change :)

Comment: Trying to work around this issue, my request are sent from a django app running on 0.0.0.0:5000. Should I specify the port number on the Google Console?

Comment: I tried that and also tried naming the 0.0.0.0 IP as localhost on my hosts file. Still not chance. Can you take a look at my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11967729/places-api-not-accepting-referer I'd appreciate that