# Places API not accepting referer

Tags: jquery, google-places-api

I've read almost all posts refering to this issue. Most of the answers were "Use Javascript API instead". I don't think that is a valid answer. I'm trying to set the referers on the Google's API Console so I can test both locally and from my dev server.

This is my API key from the Google's API console:
[image]

This is my request:

```
Request URL:https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=a&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyABBKjubUcAk69Kijktx-XXXXXXXXXX
Accept:*/*
Origin:http://localhost:5000
Referer:http://localhost:5000/users/profile/edit/location/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_4) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.75 Safari/537.1
```

I'm getting the well-known error:

```
Origin http://localhost:5000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I have also tried the "Any referer" API key with no success. 
Aren't this referers setted in order to allow this kind of AJAX calls?
I'm running a Django app on a Gunicorn server, can it be something related to the '5000' port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok there is an other solution that should work:

Try using a ssh tunnel.

If you use [localtunnel](http://progrium.com/localtunnel/) the setup is quite easy.

- Step 1: Run `sudo gem install localtunnel` in your Terminal
- Step 2: Run your local web server on any port! Let's say you're running Apache on port 8080.
- Step 3: Now run localtunnel passing it the port to share. The first time you run localtunnel you have to point to a public SSH key. Check the README if you need help.

Here's an example:
`$ localtunnel -k ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub 8080`

You should see something like this:
Port 8080 is now publicly accessible from http://8bv2.localtunnel.com ...

You can now put this URI into the Google Console.

But be aware that your localhost is publicly available when you use this solution.

Comment: I'll try it and give some feedback. Thank you!